# should add date to each row in DB when csv file is uploaded using java

Tags: java, file, csv

i have a csv file which has almost 10k records and in which there is no field like date,but when i store csv file to DB,that created date should be inserted in same table.the code which i wrote is shown below.

```
public void insertData(final InputStream inputStream, final String originalFilename, final User user)
        throws ServiceException {
    LOGGER.entry("FileName", originalFilename, "LoggedinUser", user.getName());
    final File file = new File(originalFilename);
    if (originalFilename.endsWith(.csv)) //to check csv notation {
        try {
            final BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
            final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),"UTF-8"));
            int rowcount = 0;
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (rowcount == 0) {
                    rowcount++;
                    continue;
                }
                writer.write(line);
                writer.newLine();
                rowcount++;
            }
            bufReader.close();
            writer.close();
            try {
                DataDAO.insertDataFromCSV(file, "Data"); //method to insert into DB
            } catch (DAOException dexc) {
                final String errorMsg = "Exception while processing DAO call to save imported CSV File";
                LOGGER.error(errorMsg, dexc);
                throw new ServiceException(errorMsg, dexc);
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            final String errorMsg = "Exception while reading from the file or writing to the file";
            LOGGER.error(errorMsg, ioe);
        }
    }
}



 DataDao.insertDataFromCsv

public void insertEnrichmentDataFromCSV(final File file, final String type) 
throws DAOException {
LOGGER.entry();
try {
LOGGER.info("Batch insertion of " + type + "  into database from 
file : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
final StringBuffer loadQuery = new StringBuffer(DAOConstants.QUERY_START + 
file.getPath());
if ("Data".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
loadQuery.append(DAOConstants.DATA_QUERY_START + 
DAOConstants.DATA_QUERY);
}

this.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations().
execute(loadQuery.toString());
LOGGER.info("Successfully inserted " + enrichmentType + " in to DB ");
} catch (DataAccessException exception) {
final String errorMessage = "Exception while performing batch insertion of " 
+ enrichmentType + " into database";
LOGGER.error(errorMessage, exception);
throw new DAOException(errorMessage, exception);
}
LOGGER.exit();

}


DAOConstants.Java

public final class DAOConstants {
public static final String QUERY_START = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '";
public static final String PUPPET_QUERY = " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (pe_group,data_master,pe_environment,cert_name,host_name,serial_number,iptables_status,kernel,product_name,project,department,cluster_name,architecture,citrix_version,dcenv,iis_version,is_virtual,operating_system,operating_system_maj_release,physical_processor_count,processor_count,postgres_default_version,role,sql_version,websphere_profiles,websphere_version,was,dotnet_latest_version,firefox_version,httpd_status,oracle,sybase,mq,mysql,mysql_version,jboss_version,java_version,data_master_url,httpd_process,apache_version,created_by)";
public static final String PUPPET_QUERY_START = "' INTO TABLE puppet_data 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
private DAOConstants() {
}
}
```

This is my code to store csv file into DB please can some one suggest how to add inserteddate to every row in table
Ex: my csv data is a,b,c  but when i store into DB it should store as
a  b  c  date for every record so can some one please suggest me

Comment: Can you show the code for this method DataDAO.insertDataFromCSV(file, "Data")  ?

Comment: Which database are you using?  If you are using mysql you can get the database to set the date at the point of insertion by having a column like so: created_date DATETIME NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: You already seem to be copying the csv line by line so why do you not just add the date at the end of each line in your while loop before putting it to writer?

Comment: @Dinomaster actually i have excel sheet which iam sending as csv file so i want the insertion date to be inserted in DB

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo i am just writing insert statement to insert the fields into DB

Comment: @karen if we keep default TIMESTAMP then it will store the date at the time of table creation but i want date of insertion

Comment: @vyas created_date DATETIME NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will set the created_date row to the date the row is inserted.  If this code is added to an existing table then all the rows that currently exist will default to the date the command is run.  To work out the dates the existing rows were inserted depends on what you want to use to set this value as it probably wont exist anywhere. Using the default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP means you don't need to set the current_date field as the database will do it for you.

Comment: @vyas when you write insert statements, then you can include a date value as the last column. You can create a new Date(); and use it in every row, or if you want to store a long value you could use System.currentTimeMillis() method to get the value.

Comment: @karen i followed your suggestion and changed my db column as created_date DATETIME NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,and i inserted my csv data for the first time,then iam able to get the date but when second time i reinserted the data then also iam getting the same date which i got earlir

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo i posted my insertData FromCsv method,you can see now

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options possible here:

**SQL Default value**

Depending on your DB you can add an default to a column specification that will automatically at the value of the date to that record upon insertion. for instance in postgress you would get:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    A     varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY,
    B     varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    C     varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    date  TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now()::timestamp
);
```

**Insert through JDBC**

If you handle the insert in java you can simply use at it to your JDBC statement. If your using an prepared statement this would look something like:

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO things VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
st.setObject(1, A);
st.setObject(2, B);
st.setObject(3, C);
st.setObject(4, dateTime);
st.executeUpdate(); st.close();
```

Comment: **Incorrect.** `LocalDateTime` is exactly the **wrong class** to use here. Purposely lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, this class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Here you should be using a moment in UTC, either `Instant` (always in UTC) or `OffsetDateTime` set to `ZoneOffset.UTC`. The database column should be of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (and definitely *not* the `WITHOUT` type).

Comment: @BasilBourque correct. I have adjusted my examples. Though reading the question again. A sql date and local date would have been sufficient

Comment: Better. I would suggest passing `ZoneOffset.UTC` explicitly to `OffsetDateTime.now`. Moments should generally be recorded in UTC. Most databases I know of such as Postgres adjust to UTC from any given zone/offset, so you may not need to. But it does not hurt to do so explicitly in your code.

Comment: @Dinomaster as you shown in code i have no option to insert values through jdbc as i was uploading a csv file which doesnot have a field called date so it is not possible to insert csv file seperately and date seperately

Comment: In that case the default in sql is probably the option for you.

Comment: The most problems with time related information stem from the lack of time zone information. So while UTC does solve the problem of timestamps being ambiguous, it is not a general solution. Generally moments should be stored with time zone information. Application specific design choices may sometimes make the zone information unnecessary, in which case UTC is ok. But we've passed the phase when disk space was a problem a long time ago so generally it ius always is better to play safe and just store the complete time data. Your successors will thank you.